# Loading Chrome Android Intents from an iframe

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, android-intent

I'm trying to use Chrome's new Intent:// structure, and I've determined these intent URLs don't resolve when inside an iframe.

For example:

```
iframe.html
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>

test.html
<iframe src="iframe.html" width="300px" height="300px"> </iframe>
```

When you click on the link, you'll get a 302 UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME within the iframe.  This happens both Chrome and Chrome Beta.

Is there any plan to support this use case?  What is the reasoning behind this design choice?  Is there any way I can load an intent from an iframe?

Thanks,

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: No, it is a potential security risk.

I have replicated the three ways developers used it here http://jsbin.com/ozecok/latest (all fail)

Intents are the officially supported way to launch Android applications from the web and you have to do that either via a user gesture in the host page (not an iframe) or via a redirect to the intent syntax.

Comment: I think you may have missed the question.  He *is* using an intent URI.  I reproduced his test, running Chrome 28.  Clicking the link shows a sad-face icon within the iframe.

However, it *does* work when I load iframe.html *directly* (i.e. in a top-level window, NOT via an iframe) and click the link.   It takes me to Google Play showing the Barcode Scanner ZXing Team app, showing the URI pname:com.google.zx...

Comment: Let me clarify in the answer (I could swear the question changed).  You can't do this.

Comment: So to summarize the jsbin code sample:
All of the following **work** fine at the *top level*, but **fail** when run from within an *iframe*:

(1) `<a href="intent: ...">` user click 
(2) `window.location = "intent: ..."`  no user action, but current frame
(3) `click.onclick = function() { window.location = "intent: ..."` script, but with user gesture

Comment: If I could repeat the OP's question: *What is the reasoning behind this design choice?*

Comment: More to the point: Is there a way to fall back to a website, rather than to Google Play?  (perhaps limiting the fallback website to one associated with the app in the Google Play store)

Comment: Security is the reason as given in the answer.

Comment: No way to fall back to a website.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `target="_blank"` in your link tag, this worked for me.